# Cross Fade Arbitrary Number of Videos ffmpeg Efficiently

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I have a series of videos named 'cut_xxx.mp4' where xxx represents a number 000 through 999. I want to do a cross fade on an arbitrary number of them to create a compilation, and each fade should last 4 seconds long.  Currently, I'm doing this with Python, but I suspect this is not the most efficient way:

```
import subprocess    
def get_length(filename):
  result = subprocess.run(["ffprobe", "-v", "error", "-show_entries",
                          "format=duration", "-of",
                          "default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1", filename],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  return float(result.stdout)

CROSS_FADE_DURATION = 4

basevideo = 'cut_000.mp4'
for ii in range(total_videos - 1):
  fade_start = math.floor(get_length(basevideo) - CROSS_FADE_DURATION) # new one
  outfile = f'cross_fade_{ii}.mp4'
  append_video = f'cut_{str(ii+1).zfill(3)}.mp4'
  cfcmd = f'ffmpeg -y -i {basevideo} -i {append_video} -filter_complex "xfade=offset={fade_start}:duration={CROSS_FADE_DURATION}" -an {outfile}'
  basevideo = outfile
  subprocess.call(cfcmd)
  print(fade_start)
```

I specifically remove the audio with `-an` because I'll add an audio track later. The issue I see here is that I'm compressing the video over and over again with each individual video file I add to the compilation because I'm only adding one video at a time and then re-encoding.

There should be a way to cross fade multiple videos together into a compilation, but I'm not sure what this would look like or how I would get it to work for an arbitrary number of video files of different durations. Any idea on what that monolithic ffmppeg command would look like or how I could automatically generate it given a list of videos and their durations?

Comment: Monolithic will be substantially slower IMHO because ffmpeg does not have a mechanism to sequentially process its inputs. All input files are opened simultaneously hogging memory and more frequent cache swapping.

Comment: Your method's bottleneck right now is that you are needlessly reencoding repeatrdly as you commented. I would add fade in and fade out to each video independently then use `concat` muxer to join all the files without reencoding (`-c copy`). This should speed up your script substantially. I'd be happy to spell it out tomorrow if interested.

Comment: @kesh, yes, I would definitely be interested because I'm not completely familiar with how to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid repeated re-encoding by first reencode each file using a pair of `fade` filters on each file followed by a "concat-copy".

For the first step:

```
ffmpeg -in url_in -vf fade=in:d={t_fade},fade=out:st={d-t_fade}:d={t_fade} \
       -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -enc_time_base 0 -an url_out
```

Here, `t_fade = CROSS_FADE_DURATION/2` and `d` is the duration of each file. The trio of output options (`pix_fmt`, `r`, and `enc_time_base`) are the critical common parameters among all your faded files for the next step. Use what's appropriate for your use case for `pix_fmt` & `r`.

Assuming the outputs are `faded_cut_###.mp4` then you need to compose a ffconcat text script file like so:

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file faded_cut_000.mp4
file faded_cut_001.mp4
file faded_cut_002.mp4
file faded_cut_003.mp4
...
```

Then combine them all, run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -in {script} -c copy -y output.mp4
```

Below is how I tested it with my `ffmpegio` package (if interested, `pip install ffmpegio-core`):

```py
from os import path
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
import ffmpegio

srcfiles = [...] # list of source file paths

# get durations of the video (ffprobe calls)
# equivalent to: ffprobe -of default=nk=1:nw=1 -show_entries format=duration url
durs = [ffmpegio.probe.query(url, fields=("duration",))[0] for url in srcfiles]

print('video durations': durs)

# transcode with fading effects
def add_fades(url_in, url_out, d):
    t_fade = 1  # duration of each half of cross fading
    expr = f"fade=in:d={t_fade},fade=out:st={d-t_fade}:d={t_fade}"

    ffmpegio.transcode(
        url_in,
        url_out,
        vf=expr,
        pix_fmt="yuv420p",
        r=25,
        enc_time_base=0,
        an=None,
        # show_log=True,  # Omit/False to hide FFmpeg logs
    )
    # equivalent to 
    # ffmpeg -in url_in -vf expr -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -enc_time_base 0 -an url_out

    return url_out

# work in a temporary directory
with TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    # tmpdir = "sandbox" # you may use a folder of your choice

    # apply fading and get the urls of new video in tmpdir
    faded_urls = [
        add_fades(url, path.join(tmpdir, path.basename(url)), d)
        for url, d in zip(srcfiles, durs)
    ]

    # use concat muxer to copy-transcode
    ffconcat = ffmpegio.FFConcat()
    ffconcat.add_files(faded_urls)
    with ffconcat: # creates the script file
        print(ffconcat.script) # to see the script
        ffmpegio.transcode(
            ffconcat,
            "output.mp4", # final output path here
            f_in="concat",
            c="copy",
            safe_in=0,
            overwrite=True, # adds -y
            show_log=True,  # False to hide FFmpeg logs
        )
    # equivalent to 
    # ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -in script -c copy -y output.mp4
```

[edit: added]

This double-`fade` solution is not exactly the same as `xfade`. If you must have the true crossfading effect, `add_fades` needs to be modified to take 2 inputs (main and the other to fade into at the end of the main video). The trick here is to make sure you're splicing the input files correctly so when they are concatenated you get smooth transitions.

Comment: The resulted mp4 is not playable using this code. I took two 4k images, concatenated them and got mp4 which I cannot play not in VLC and not in Windows media player. any idea why?

Comment: Are you adding fades to each image?

Comment: Is this really the only way to do it? Surely there is a filter that will just cross fade in a single command?

Comment: Well, no, there are other possibilities if you're processing files (not live streams). Probe the durations of all your files, then configure a chain of `xfade`s. The FFmpeg filters is purely causal (do not know when stream ends) so you need to do some legwork for them.